# Should logs for /opt go in /var/opt or /var/log?

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, graphite, fhs

A package I'm using ([Graphite](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.10/install.html)) insists on installing into `/opt/graphite`.

Should logs go into `/var/opt/graphite/log`, or `/var/log/graphite`?

Presume we want to be as FHS as possible.  I'm using CentOS 6--would it vary by *NIX/distro?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @Andrew (Centos 6.  Thx!)

Comment: If you're as anal about FHS compliance as I am, I've produced CentOS 6 RPMs of Graphite that are patched to be FHS-friendly: http://holyhandgrenade.org/blog/2011/10/fhs-compliant-graphite-packages-for-rhelcentos-6/

Comment: @jgoldschrafe Awesome!  However, your `rpm-python-carbon` and `rpm-python-whisper` links appear to be broken?  Neat patch, thanks!

Comment: I need to update that post. They're renamed to rpm-carbon and rpm-whisper on GitHub.

Comment: This package is in EPEL as `graphite-web`. If you have EPEL configured on your system, can just `yum install graphite web`. (And these install in standard FHS locations, including logging to /var/log/graphite-web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would vary by */NIX/distro. Therefore, I'd put them in /opt/graphite/log : Software that install in opt should not expect /var/anything to be available.

For example, /var/opt does not even exist on a default FreeBSD installation.

However, nowadays /var/log/graphite is a safe bet : I haven't seen logs in /usr/adm/logs or /var/adm for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever installing a package from source, I would keep it with the following layout:

```
/usr/local/<package_name>
|-- bin
|   |-- 
|   |-- 
|   `-- 
|-- lib
|   |-- 
|   |-- 
|   `-- 
|-- conf (or etc)
|   |-- 
|   |-- 
|   `-- 
`-- var
    |-- lock
    |-- log
    `-- run
```

You may also take a look at this: http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.10/install.html#default-installation-layout

Comment: According to the FHS, `/usr` [should not be writable](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#THEUSRHIERARCHY) (which would seem to preclude `/usr/local/.../var`).  However, that installation link does have important tips for changing the install path, so thanks.